# How to translate "detangling knot" or "knot that unties"?

Tags: translation, characters, transliteration

I need to use the expression "detangling knot" (knot that unties). It's for a poem and I should write it with two kanji and no more... is it possible or is it better for me to use something like this *開結* (should be "untied/open knot")?

Comment: It's not really "knot easy to untie", but more "knot that unties another knot" (I know, it sounds absurd). If it's too strange (or too long) to translate I can change the sense replacing it with "untied knot" in the meaning of "knot already untied".

Comment: *kanji*? You might be on the wrong SE. Try japanese.stackexchange.com

Comment: "knot that unties another knot" is not logical. People use hands to untie knot. A knot cannot untie another knot.

Answer (score 1):

**活结**

*Pleco Basic Chinese-English Dictionary*

> knot that can be undone by a pull; slipknot (opp. 死结)
>
> 系了个活结
> xì le ge huójié
> make a slipknot

---

**活扣**

*ABC*

> slipknot; knot that can be easily untied

Comment: How about the word: 解结?

Comment: Never heard that before, the two in your answer are the most common.